# Conda: Download Packages to Local Custom Channel

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to set up a local Python repository to use with conda as a custom channel, as outlined here:

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/create-custom-channels.html

I'm doing this because I don't have access to the Internet from this server. What I've done make a new folder named `/opt/local-channel` with subfolders `linux-64` and `noarch`. I copied all the Python packages from the Anaconda distribution into the `/opt/local-channel/linux-64` folder and then indexed them with conda.

So far this works. However, there are some packages (e.g. jellyfish) that I still need to add to the channel. I do have Internet access from another server, so I want to know if there's a way I can download the packages directly from one of the online repos to my local machine, then copy them to my local channel and re-index everything with conda.

I've read the documentation from conda and looked at other questions, but I can't find out how to just download a package straight to a channel without installing it into an environment. I want to do it through conda if possible so the dependencies are managed (i.e. so that when I install a package to the channel, it also installs any dependencies).